# How to verify if the browser-side tooltip type validation message is displayed or not

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify using selenium python that if the browser-side validation message is displayed or not.

When we enter some invlaid input and try to submit a validation message as a tooltip is shown on that input field and I want to verify if it is visible or not

**I tried this:**
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Password']).get_attribute("validationMessage")`

The above code does returns the correct browser based validation message, but the problem is that it always returns the correct message reagardless of the message visiblility

I want to verify if the browser side validation message is displayed after clicking on the Submit button
[This is the message i want to verify if this is visible or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmJzL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's general validation message, there is no point to test it by visibility.
`validationNessage` is property that contains only text of validation message. There is nothing in it that points to visibility.

Usually validation is tested on backend side.
However, if you want to test it on frontend, you can check if element has `required` attribute.

```py
input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[placeholder='Password']")))
assert input.get_attribute('required') == 'true'
```

If this attribute is present, validation message would appear after triggered logic was performed.

Trigger logic itself should be tested by unit tests (they are more quick and flaky-protected).

Comment: So if the browser-based validation is not shown that is a problem from the browser side and not in the website's code.